# Sublimetext 3 build - python - No such file or directory

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I try to run my build on sublime as presented:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python.exe", "-u", "file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

And when I run it, it says No such file exists

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe: can't open file 'file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I'm not really sure what am I suppose to do, because the file is there.

Comment: Your build system is literally telling it to run a python file named `file` which is almost certainly not what you meant to do. The build system needs to contain `$file` as the last argument, which will be replaced with the name of the current file when you invoke the build.

Comment: Well... I fell silly now. Thanks that did the trick. It is the first build file I do hehe

Comment: A common phenomena in computer science is not noticing simple things like that until someone else points them out. :)